# Lossless decomposition to get BCNF (normal form)

Tags: database-design

Let's say I have a relation as follows:

R(A,B,C,D) {A->B, B->C}

Can I losslessly decompose R into component relations in BCNF while preserving functional dependencies?

What if I changed it to:

R(A,B,C,D) {A->B, B->C, BC->D)?

I believe that the first cannot decomposose into BCNF. I believe with the addition of BC->D, it CAN be decomposed, but am unsure. Can anyone help clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you can decompose in BCNF while preserving the functional dependencies.

In the first case, the unique key is AD, and the decomposition using the analysis algorithm is the following (each relation is shown with a cover of the dependencies projected over it):

R1 < (A B) ,
{ A → B } >

R2 < (B C) ,
{ B → C } >

R3 < (A D) ,
{ } >

And you can note that both dependencies are preserved, since we have two relations that have the attributes of the dependencies.

In the second case, a canonical cover of the dependencies is:

{ A → B,
B → C,
B → D }

the key is A, and the decomposition using the analysis algorithm is the following (again, each relation is shown with a cover of the dependencies projected over it):

R1 < (B C D) ,
{ B → C,
B → D } >

R2 < (A B) ,
{ A → B } >

We can note that the decomposition preserves all the dependencies.